# Does React (with create react app) automatically preload fonts defined in .css stylesheets?

Tags: css, reactjs, performance-testing

I have a react site hosted from a static S3 bucket. Within my App.js I am importing an .scss file where fonts are defined as such:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Coco Gothic";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("/assets/fonts/CocoGothic-UltraLightItalic.woff") format("woff");
}
```

When I profile the site loading with Google's PageSpeed insights, the top optimisation factor it suggests is to preload key requests by adding `<link rel=preload>`, with two font files listed as the top culprits. If React is not already doing this, is there any way of providing a hint for it to do so?

Comment: I'm also facing this, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I don’t know if this is a workaround or a legit solution but I fixed it by adding the font preload tag in the index.html file